# Can you skip XML Elements when performing XML Serialization using Complex Objects in a T4 template?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, t4, entity-framework-6.1

Okay so I have been doing some hacking to basically hookup a t4 template to create custom attributes and properties to make a complex object serialize.  And it works great, except some of the 'bridge' tables in my database I would rather skip over and show their denormalized values versus an arbitrary level of navigation.  It works great for normalization of entry, not so much when I want a serialized object.

My question would be:
Is it even possible to skip a class being normalized and instead show it's child in relation to it's grandparent element instead?  Or do I have to make a denormalized view in the database or more custom objects to do this?

I would prefer to just add some attributes to ignore data rather than build even more complex objects.  I am not familiar as much with serialization methods and their attributes in .NET as some people may be.  So I have simulated as best I could what a generic of my T4 would generate and some custom attributes I have added to it for xml serialization.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MyExtensionMethods;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static DataManipulation dm = new DataManipulation();

        [Serializable]
        public class ValueTable
        {
            public ValueTable()
            {
                this.Bridges = new List<BridgeTable>();
            }

            [XmlIgnore]
            public int ValueID { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }

            [XmlIgnore]
            public virtual List<BridgeTable> Bridges { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class BridgeTable
        {
            [XmlIgnore]
            public int BridgeID { get; set; }
            [XmlIgnore]
            public int ThingID { get; set; }
            [XmlIgnore]
            public int ValueID { get; set; }

            public virtual ValueTable ValueTable { get; set; }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class Thing
        {
            public Thing()
            {
                this.Bridges = new List<BridgeTable>();
            }

            public int ThingID { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("elements")]
            public virtual List<BridgeTable> Bridges { get; set; }
        }

        public static Thing GetThing()
        {
            List<BridgeTable> bridges = new List<BridgeTable>{
                new BridgeTable{ BridgeID = 1, ThingID = 1, ValueTable = new ValueTable{ ValueID = 1, Value = "Shirt"}},
                new BridgeTable{ BridgeID = 1, ThingID = 1, ValueTable = new ValueTable{ ValueID = 2, Value = "Pants"}},
                new BridgeTable{ BridgeID = 1, ThingID = 1, ValueTable = new ValueTable{ ValueID = 3, Value = "Shoes"}}
            };

            Thing thing = new Thing
            {
                ThingID = 1,
                value = "I am a thing",
                Bridges = bridges
            };

            return thing;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thing thing = GetThing();
            string xml = thing.ToXmlText();  // propriatary extension method to convert a generic complex or simple type to xml.
            Console.WriteLine(xml);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I get this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Thing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ThingID>1</ThingID>
  <value>I am a thing</value>
  <elements>
    <ValueTable>
      <Value>Shirt</Value>
    </ValueTable>
  </elements>
  <elements>
    <ValueTable>
      <Value>Pants</Value>
    </ValueTable>
  </elements>
  <elements>
    <ValueTable>
      <Value>Shoes</Value>
    </ValueTable>
  </elements>
</Thing>
```

But it would be a lot cooler if I could get this WITHOUT having to make up brand new container objects just do the serialization.  Instead having some attribute like [IgnoreXMLElement], so far no dice though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Thing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ThingID>1</ThingID>
  <value>I am a thing</value>
  <elements>
      <Value>Shirt</Value>
  </elements>
  <elements>
      <Value>Pants</Value>
  </elements>
  <elements>
      <Value>Shoes</Value>
  </elements>
</Thing>
```

Even better:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Thing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ThingID>1</ThingID>
  <value>I am a thing</value>
  <elements>
      <Value>Shirt</Value>
      <Value>Pants</Value>
      <Value>Shoes</Value>
  </elements>
</Thing>
```

I am curious if a view could potentially do this.  However I would be having nav properties more complex than this example that sometimes are one to many as well as one to one.  So keeping the tables as they are and serializing through their generated t4 classes would be preferable to taking more time to create a denormalized view.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried flattening the collection before building the XML or just manually promoting the child nodes after? Also, is your xml output really as described in he question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your t4 template looks like, but you can always manually manipulate the xml after generation (as part of the template) or in your ToXmlText() method, something like:

```
// Assuming the xml looks like the sample you provided
public static XElement ToXml(this string text)
{
    var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
    // grab the first parent
    var parent = xml.Descendants("elements").FirstOrDefault();
    // grab the Value nodes
    var nodes = xml.Descendants("Value").Where (x => x.Parent != xml && x.Parent != parent);
    // add the Value nodes to the first elements node
    parent.Add(nodes.ToArray());
    // remove all the branches the Value elements came from
    nodes.ToList()
          .ForEach(x=> x.Ancestors()
            .TakeWhile(a=> a != xml)
            .Where (a => a != parent)
            .Remove());
    return xml;
}
```

This all assumes the XML closely resembles your example of course...

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!  I knew there was probably something with System.Xml.Linq to do a custom changing without changing my structure too much or creating new container elements.